# An Issue in fetching result with pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I restricted the value of the comment up to 7. 
With the below query resulting value of the comments are shifting towards the right side prefixing with `NULL` value.

```
set @row_number=0;

select id, userid,content,timestamp,comment_count,
min(case when seq=1 then comment end) as comment1,
min(case when seq=1 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime1,
min(case when seq=2 then comment end) as comment2,
min(case when seq=2 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime2,
min(case when seq=3 then comment end) as comment3,
min(case when seq=3 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime3,
min(case when seq=4 then comment end) as comment4,
min(case when seq=4 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime4,
min(case when seq=5 then comment end) as comment5,
min(case when seq=5 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime5,
min(case when seq=6 then comment end) as comment6,
min(case when seq=6 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime6,
min(case when seq=7 then comment end) as comment7,
min(case when seq=7 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime7
from
(
select *,
        (@row_number := @row_number +1) as seq from 
(SELECT DISTINCT ft.ID as ID, ft.userid, ft.content, ft.timestamp, ft.comments as comment_count, ftc.comment, ftc.timestamp as comment_timestamp, uq.username, uq.avatar FROM users uq,
feed_item ft 
LEFT JOIN feed_item_comment ftc ON ftc.postid = ft.ID
LEFT JOIN user_friends uf ON uf.friendid = ftc.userid 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = uf.friendid WHERE uq.ID = ft.userid AND ft.userid
IN 
(SELECT u.ID FROM users u WHERE u.ID 
IN (SELECT uf.friendid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.userid = 1) 
OR u.ID IN 
(SELECT uf.userid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.friendid = 1) 
OR
u.ID = 1
)ORDER BY ft.ID DESC, ftc.timestamp DESC)X)Y
group by id
```

**Actual Result:**

```
id  userid  content     timestamp   cmt_count   comment1    commenttime1    comment2      commenttime2  comment3    commenttime3    comment4    commenttime4    comment5    commenttime5    comment6                        commenttime6 comment7   commenttime7
1   14      How are     14:07:00    2           NULL        NULL            NULL          NULL          NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL                            NULL         Look Good  20:00:00
            you?
2   14      How are     13:06:42    3           NULL        NULL            NULL          NULL          Not Good    15:05:10        Fine        15:00:15        Fine        15:00:15        Not Bad After All your efforts! 08:13:10     NULL           NULL
            you doing?
3   1       This is     13:12:31    2           new cmt     14:00:15        manju comment 13:17:31      NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL                            NULL         NULL           NULL
            manju
```

**Expected Result**

```
id  userid  content             timestamp   comment_count   comment1        commenttime1    comment2    commenttime2 comment3                           commenttime3
1   14      How are you?        14:07:00    2               Look Good       20:00:00        So I'm!     20:10:00     NULL                               NULL
2   14      How are you doing?  13:06:42    3               Fine            15:00:15        Not Good    15:05:10     Not Bad After All your efforts!    08:13:10
3   1       This is manju       13:12:31    2               manju comment   13:17:31        new cmt     14:00:15     NULL                               NULL
```

You may try the above query with

### [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b05a8/5/1)

I want to get rid of NULL values occupying with the comment1,2... and so that the value of the comment should stick to the first place otherwise NULL should be filled in case if it doesn't have the value.

Comment: Try `MAX` instead of `MIN`.